# Covectors, Metric Tensors and Unit Vectors

Tags: dual-spaces

In orthogonal cartesian coordinates $c\cdot c=|c|^2$ is the square of length of the vector $c$.

In oblique coordinates the square of the length of $c = c * g * c$ where g is the metric tensor and $g*c$ is a covector.

If $e_x$ and $e_y$ are the basis vectors of vector $c$ then how does one calculate the new basis vectors $e_x'$ and $e_y'$ of $g*c$?

Am I correct in assuming that $e_x'$ will be perpendicular to $e_y'$?

A relevant video can be seen [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AKPZkHvqTao&list=PL6oNjS6Kc-nTIPkICpvWC1lBEBRsXrIlg&index=2).

Comment: Can you please write this question more clearly? You will get a much better answer if you explain and set things up more coherently.

Comment: I think the answer is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_coordinates

Comment: Your dual basis, $\{e^i\}$, will be completely determined by your vector basis, $\{e_i\}$, and the identity;

$$e^i(e_j)=\delta^i_j$$

Comment: @Volk Thank you. That was the answer I was looking for.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_basis